# GCP command not created ~/.kube/config

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

In my gitlab pipeline script, I'm executing below command to create ~/.kube/config.

```
- terraform init
- NAME=`echo 'var.name' | terraform console -var-file terraform.tfvars | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' `
- REGION=`echo 'var.region' | terraform console -var-file terraform.tfvars | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' `
- PROJECT=`echo 'var.project' | terraform console -var-file terraform.tfvars | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' `
- gcloud container clusters get-credentials $NAME --zone $REGION
```

**Output**

> Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data. kubeconfig entry generated
> for test-sb-cluster.

But the config file not created in the $HOME directory and pipeline fails with below error

> Error: could not open kubeconfig "~/.kube/config": stat
> /root/.kube/config: no such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

If you are logged in as root `~/` refers to `/root` directory. Not `/home/user`

Comment: The gitlab runner will run as root user and we are checking in /root directory only. The .kube/config file not created in the /root directory

Comment: Your script should not have the permission to create files in /root

Comment: It has permission to create directory in /root directory. I tired it and there is no error thrown when I executed `gcloud container clusters get-credentials $NAME --zone $REGION`